# Need some information

Tags: system-installation, info

OK so i am new to Ubuntu, and i need some info. So i have an operating system of windows xp (hence why i am new to all this stuff) and sort of old fashioned i guess, but anyway on to my questions...

So right as of a few minutes ago i started the Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop download, and i was wondering what am i downloading to my PC? am i downloading the whole operating system or what is going on? Now for my second question will i need a blank CD or usb thumbdrive after the instillation? i have blank cds with a maximum of 702 MB.

Sorry that i am such a newb to all of this but i do need some support. If any one has any info/help that would be much appreciated!! thank you for your time and have a nice day.

Comment: Answer to the question 1-> No, you are not downloading entire OS. question 2-> Yes, you need a DVD (not CD, because of the size) or USB thumbdrive **before** installing Ubuntu for **installation**.

And check the link in above comment for more detailed instruction

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading the full operating system image, which needs to be burned to a DVD or written to a USB Stick. You can't burn to a 700MB CD because the image is larger than the space on the disk.

Here's a [guide for the USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) and here's a guide for [burning a DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).